# How do I find out what caused our mail server to get listed in UCEPROTECT-1?

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention, velo, blacklist

Our IP address recently got listed on UCEPROTECT-1 as a potential spam address, and we aren't able to figure out how to stop this. According to their website, UCEPROTECT-1 listing happens when: `IP's get listed in Level 1 automatically if they either try to deliver e-mails to spamtraps or if they are involved in port scans or probes or any kind of attacks against our servers`

Some research online suggests that the only way to ensure it doesn't happen again is to find out what is triggering these spam traps and plug them.

Any idea how we can go about looking for what is triggering these automatic listings? Any help would be appreciated!

**Some background:**

We use GSuite for our email servers, wix.com for our website, and namecheap.com for our DNS.
We'd originally paid to not be listed in the UCEPROTECT-2 and 3 listings but were automatically removed as soon as we got listed under UCEPROTECT-1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how G-Suite works but in general check

- logfiles of the outgoing e-mail servers for days with "strange" recipients patterns or for more e-mails than on other days
- if your domain is listed on other blacklists, maybe that is giving you other hints

The problem is: if you are using the outgoing e-mail servers from Google and some of them are listed on UCEProtect (because other G-Suite customers are sending spam, mostly without knowing it cause they are hacked), you have little chance of fixing this yourselve. This is not really uncommon, me.com/icloud.com (17.58.63.0/24) is listed at UCEProtect right now too.